# URL Rewrite options: How to exclude files and directories?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm using the URL rewrite middleware in ASP.NET Core, and I'm trying to make the rewrite work *only* if the request does not point to an existing file or directory.

Here's the code I'm using:

```cs
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRewrite(@"^(.*)$", "index.php/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);

app.UseRewriter(options);
```

<sup>**In:** `Startup::Configure()`</sup>

In IIS, using `web.config`, I can define something like this:

```xml
<rule name="RewriteRule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Please notice the **`negate="true"`** attribute on `matchType="IsFile"` and `matchType="IsDirectory"`, for `input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"`, which is the request path.

I do not want to load an IIS-style rewrite ruleset with [`AddIISUrlRewrite()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1), nor I'm confident that it'll work.

Is it possible to exclude existing static files from the rewrite request in ASP.NET Core? If so, how?

Comment: If anyone asks, [**PeachPie**](https://www.peachpie.io/) is used to invoke the `index.php` script within .NET core.  That portion works [fine](https://github.com/peachpiecompiler/peachpie/issues/859#issuecomment-707974127).

Answer (score 1):

I wound up doing something like this - my static files are hosted under a sub-folder "Web":

```
var fileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Web"));

app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions() { StaticFileProvider = fileProvider }
    .Add(context =>
        {
            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Web", out var subPath))
            {
                if (subPath != "/" && context.StaticFileProvider.GetDirectoryContents(subPath).Exists)
                {
                    context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
                }
                else if (context.StaticFileProvider.GetFileInfo(subPath).Exists)
                {
                    context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
                }
            }
        })
    .AddRewrite("^Web/(.*)$", "Web/index.html", true));

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                       {
                           FileProvider = fileProvider,
                           RequestPath = "/Web",
                       });
```